# How to determine the column properties of the results returned by the database in Qt through parameters？

Tags: database, qt

I try to input multiple parameters through the QString.arg method, but the returned result is not what I need, and I don't understand the difference between statement 1 and statement 2?

```
`void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString contents=ui->lineEdit->text();    //获取内容
    qryModel=new QSqlQueryModel(this);
    theSelection=new QItemSelectionModel(qryModel);
    QString str="x1,x2";
    qryModel->setQuery(QString("select x1,x2 from test1 where test1.x1='%1'").arg(contents));//Statement1
    qryModel->setQuery(QString("select '%1' from test1 where test1.x1='%2'").arg(str).arg(contents));//Statement2
    ui->tableView->setModel(qryModel);//数据放置进去
}
`
```

Comment: Don't see what this has to do with Qt but `select x1, x2 from test1 where test1.x1='content` is a different query than `select 'x1,x2' from test1 where test.x1='content'`. Also yopu should use prepared queries otherwise you will get in trouble when your lineedit contains e.g. `'; drop table test1;` - happy sql-injection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem has been resolved.